# How to open a certain document at login?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, terminal

I have a file:

```
mydoc.xlsx (Excel spreadsheet).
```

Is there some sort of terminal command or other setting in Excel or otherwise that makes this particular document open automatically when I login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding it to your *Login Items* in *System Preferences, Accounts*.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The simplest method : Adding its shortcut into to your startup folder.

Or you can use [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902) software which is suggested by Microsoft to create an automatic run in each login...

Comment: -1 Wrong operating system.

Comment: did you mention any operating system in your question? I don't think so...

Comment: @NT If they don't mention the OS in their question title or body text, You've gotta read the tags (he *did* tag it "osx"). If they don't mention it there either, then shame on them.